# How to have one ImageView in front of another ImageView (Background fills parent?)

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

I'm trying to have one ImageView overlap another, but I want the background ImageView to take up all the space available in its container.

This is what I have for the ImageView area:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:gravity="center">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/imagelayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight=".75"
        android:layout_gravity="center">
        <ImageView
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:id="@+id/imageView1" />
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView2"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:src="@drawable/img"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent" />
        <VideoView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight=".75"
            android:id="@+id/videoView1"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:visibility="gone" />
    </RelativeLayout>
```

And this is the output:

[image]

I want the camera preview (checkered area) to fill up the entire available space behind the person icon.

What do I need to change?

Thanks

Comment: Look into scaleType for ImageViews. Or just set the background to the image resource if you don't care about aspect ratios.

Comment: use alignleft, alignright, alignTop and alignBottom attributes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

layout_weight inside RelativeLayout doesn't work so the VideoView

```
android:layout_weight=".75"
```

doesn't have effect.

fill_parent is deprecated, and it's the same as match_parent.

If you want ImageView takes all space you must use on the ImageView

```
android:scaleType="fitXY"
```

Comment: android:scaleType="fitXY" worked. I had recently made the RelativeLayout change and hadn't removed the layout weight from VideoView. Thanks.